# Shopify 1.0 - Collection template

Tags: html, collections, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I need to change the layout of the collection from displaying only product columns (default theme inside Shopify 1.0) to showing a text-box and an image side by side at the top of every collection giving more info about every collection. The images below are of the current layout versus the layout that I need.

###### Current layout:

> [image: Image 1]

###### The layout I require:

> [image: Image 2]

I am hoping that someone who has been in the same situation could provide a solution or an app inside shopify 1.0 that could implement these changes.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to have some coding knowledge of liquid to do the same. You can get the collection image and description into the collection template using it.